# TextVIew does not display "ț" symbol

Tags: android, string, textview, char

I have a simple `TextView`, where I put a string like that: `"Curăță corect urechile copilașului tău!"`. But I see the string on display like this `"Cură ă corect urechile copilașului tău!"` - just space between chars, where must be a `"ț"` symbol.

I checked the string in `TextView` by `TextView.getText()`, and I get my original string.

This is a screenshot, also the same problem in first title: [image]

Comment: Are you using device

Comment: Yes, I am using a real device

Comment: might be the case where device doesnt support the language

Comment: I thought about it, but other symbols like "ă" or "ș" are good to display. I don't think that it is a device's problem.

Comment: You can download the Roboto font and try the same text on your computer in something like Word. At least that might reveal whether the character is supported.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set text in TextView using HTML. I hope this will work and may help you out.

```
myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("your_string"));
```

Answer (score 0):

There is still space for the letters, so perhaps it's an issue with the styling.

Change the style to default, do the letters show up?

Try adding a shadow to the textviews and see if the shadow exists (maybe the letters are somehow transparent, or the same color as the background?)

Comment: I did all that you said, but none of that have helped me. There is no shadow and changing style didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

It is more related to a font issue, default Android font doesn't support some characters. You need to try from a different font.

You can try from the following (but I think its not free)

http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=FontDownloads